# How to handle asynchronous in angular.js controller?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, angularjs

I'm new to angular.js. I'm confused with how to handle asynchronous events in the controller.

For example, in a page, I have a view named `count`. And while I click on a button, the controller increase the count by 1. But the increase is asynchronous. What I want is, when `count` changed, the view will be notified and change its value. But util the next click, the view will not change its value.

This is the code for example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div ng-controller="Controller">
      {{ count }}
      <form ng-submit="delayInc()">
        <input type="submit" value="Add" />
      </form>
    </div>

    <script>
      function Controller($scope) {
        $scope.count = 0;

        $scope.delayInc = function () {
          setTimeout(function () {
            $scope.count += 1;
          }, 1000);
        };
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

## Update:

Thanks for all your answers. But I'm asking a generate question. How about the `setTimeout` function is a http request? I know there is `$http` could do this. But what if the function is something handle a file and so on? I don't except every async call have a service for me. Do I need to write my own one if it dose not exist?

Comment: but when you do form submit then whole page is reloading and you will never see the variable's changes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`$timeout` service](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/api/ng.%24timeout) instead of the native `setTimeout`:

```
function Controller($scope, $timeout) {
    //                      ^---- Don't forget to inject the service
    $scope.count = 0;

    $scope.delayInc = function () {
        $timeout(function () {
            $scope.count += 1;
        }, 1000);
    };
}
```

Alternatively, you can tell Angular to apply your changes manually using [`Scope.$digest()`](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24digest) (the `$timeout` service shown above will effectively do this for you):

```
function Controller($scope) {
    $scope.count = 0;

    $scope.delayInc = function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $scope.count += 1;
            $scope.$digest();
        }, 1000);
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have updated my question. Could you have a look please?

Comment: @BinWang - The 2nd example in my answer can apply to the general case. But I would suggest using the Angular services where possible. If you want to write your own, you'll want to use promises - look at the [`$q` service](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/api/ng.$q).

Answer (score 0):

Due to the nature of the AngularJS $scope you need to replace the `setTimeout` call with the `$timeout` service.